How do I send all TCP and UDP traffic over tproxy without making a loop?
I'm running my proxy client on the same Linux machine I'm using the connection on. In the configuration I can tell it to tproxy to port 2500. The proxy runs on port 443, using TLS (although this part the proxy takes over managing)
So I need to use iptables or nftables to route all packets to the proxy. But I need to mark them as well, so that I don't create a loop.
My initial attempts didn't succeed, seems like my UDP packets didn't go through (I'm behind a NAT, but I don't know it's that's the issue since I'm proxying anyway). I'd like to know how it works better so I can debug it myself.
Here's my attempt:
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100

#Setup a chain DIVERT to mark packets
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT

#Use DIVERT to prevent existing connections going through TPROXY twice:
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m socket -j DIVERT

#Mark all other (new) packets and use TPROXY to pass into xray
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 2500
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 2500

#disable rp_filter and enable ip_forward
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w  net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wlp38s0.rp_filter=0

the packets just pass by my rules like they are not there

What were your initial attempts? Have you tried enabling the ip_forwarding sysctl? Did that change the behavior at all? What is your proxy client? Please include that information and show us how you have configured it.

I just included more information and tried doing the ip_forward, but something is just not working, I can load websites from the original connection without those packets being routed anywhere

I would strongly consider using a dedicated box for the tproxy, you might be able to get your current setup to work, but it will be significantly easier when you have different chains for local (proxy) traffic and remote traffic.

So I figured out one way to do it by running the xray executable as a different user:
sudo -u xray_tproxy xray -c config.json where the GID is 23333
next I created these rules
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100

# new table
iptables -t mangle -N XRAY
#  "网关所在ipv4网段" 通过运行命令"ip address | grep -w inet | awk '{print $2}'"获得，一般有多个
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY -d 192.168.2.211/24 -j RETURN


# multicast address
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY -d 224.0.0.0/3 -j RETURN


#Get this IP range by doing "ip address | grep -w "inet" | awk '{print $2}'"
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY ! -s 192.168.2.211/24 -j RETURN

# Set the mark to 1 and tproxy port 2500
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port 2500 --tproxy-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 2500 --tproxy-mark 1
# 应用规则
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j XRAY

# don't proxy gateway or the user with that GUID we created earlier
iptables -t mangle -N XRAY_MASK
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY_MASK -m owner --gid-owner 23333 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY_MASK -d 192.168.2.211/24 -j RETURN

iptables -t mangle -A XRAY_MASK -d 224.0.0.0/3 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A XRAY_MASK -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j XRAY_MASK
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -j XRAY_MASK 

and I ran them with sudo
see:
https://xtls.github.io/document/level-2/iptables_gid.html#_3-%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE%E6%9C%80%E5%A4%A7%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E6%89%93%E5%BC%80%E6%95%B0-%E8%BF%90%E8%A1%8C-xray-%E5%AE%A2%E6%88%B7%E7%AB%AF
